# VBA: Spliting cell values into rows working slowly

Tags: vba, performance

I have the following code. It's working perfectly but it's too slow.The workbook I'm using contains around 20000 rows and the code runs for about 10 min. How can I optimize my code to make it faster please?

Here is how the data looks like in one cell:

Deal/Account/Data,

Data/Account/position,

Agreement/Data

```
Sub splitByColB()
    Dim r As Range, i As Long, ar
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    
    Set r = Worksheets("Export").Range("M999999").End(xlUp)
    Do While r.Row > 1
        ar = Split(r.Value, ",")
        If UBound(ar) >= 0 Then r.Value = ar(0)
        For i = UBound(ar) To 1 Step -1
            r.EntireRow.Copy
            r.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            r.Offset(1).Value = ar(i)
        Next
        Set r = r.Offset(-1)
    Loop
    MsgBox "Operation done"
           
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
Sub Test()

    Dim DataRange As Range
    Dim DataArray As Variant
    Dim DataItem As Variant
    Dim SplitItems As Variant
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export")
        Set DataRange = .Range("M2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp))
        DataArray = DataRange
        DataRange.ClearContents
        For Each DataItem In DataArray
            SplitItems = Application.Transpose(Split(DataItem, ","))
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(SplitItems)) = SplitItems
        Next DataItem
    End With
    
End Sub
```

If the data range is a single line then `DataArray` won't be an array.  This updated code deals with that:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim DataRange As Range
    Dim DataArray As Variant
    Dim DataItem As Variant
    Dim SplitItems As Variant
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export")
        Set DataRange = .Range("M2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp)) 'Reference to all cells containing data.
        DataArray = DataRange 'Place data into an array.
        DataRange.ClearContents 'Clear the data range.
        If IsArray(DataArray) Then 'If more than one cell of data returned.
            For Each DataItem In DataArray 'Look at each item in the array.
                SplitString DataItem 'Pass the item for splitting.
            Next DataItem
        Else 'If a single cell of data returned.
            SplitString DataArray 'Pass the item for splitting.
        End If
    End With
    
End Sub

Public Sub SplitString(DataItem)

    'Split the comma delimited string.
    'Without the Transpose the data will appear as SplitItems(0), SplitItems(1), etc.
    'With Transpose the data appears as SplitItems(1,1), SplitItems(2,1) and can be placed back on sheet.
    Dim SplitItems As Variant
    SplitItems = Application.Transpose(Split(DataItem, ","))
    
    'Find the next empty cell and place the split array on the sheet.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export")
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(SplitItems)) = SplitItems
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Darren for your contribution, but your code gives a type mismatch error in this line: SplitItems = Application.Transpose(Split(DataItem, ",")). I don't know why? everything seems fine to me, what do you think?

Comment: One thing I can think of - if there's only a single item in the column M then `DataArray` won't be an array so it can't `For....Each` through the array.  That returns a Type Mismatch.  If it's not that, what's the value of `DataItem` when it errors?  Also, a figure like `12,312,312` is a numerical value so Excel stores it as `12312312` and uses number formats to put the commas in (that would return incorrect results rather than an error though).

Comment: I also noticed That you used the clear content on the column...basically the column will be empty and there's nothing to transpose?! because I still get the same error and I think that might be the issue?

Comment: Yes, it puts all the values into an array before clearing the cells (`DataArray = DataRange`).  It then works with the array before putting the values back on the sheet. I'll update my second set of code with some comments.

Comment: Could you update your original question with a sample of the type of data you're working with?  The _Edit_ button is just below the tags in the question.  I'm testing with just strings of characters in each cell:   "A, B, C, D" etc.

Comment: RE: "*If the data range is a single line then DataArray won't be an array*"  Truly one of the most annoying features in the Excel object model.